# Connecting express container to mongo container which have a volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, express, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a mean application based on [this repository](https://github.com/KrunalLathiya/Angular7CRUDExample), I've separated the api in an Express container and the front-end in an Angular one.

Now I'm trying to create the database from the official mongo image and it worked like a charm. However, when I try to add a volume to persist the data, I receive the following error:

> express_1  | Can not connect to the databaseMongoNetworkError: failed 
>       to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: 
>       connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.0.2:27017].

Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  angular:
    build: angular-app
    links:
      - express
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    networks:
      - my_network

  express:
    build: express-app
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - my_network

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/data/db"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      my_network:
        aliases:
          - mongo
```

And here is my mongoose connector :

```
mongodb://mongo:27017/ng7crud
```

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : As asked by @michalhosna, the result of  `docker-compose logs mongo`:

```
Attaching to projet_mongo_1
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.336+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.346+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=2523b067e6fc
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.346+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.5
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.346+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.347+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.377+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:22.385+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:33.474+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1548976293:474858][1:0x7f935195fa40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 1/24064 to 2/256
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:34.376+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1548976294:376222][1:0x7f935195fa40], txn-recover: Recovering log 1 through 2
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.031+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1548976295:31496][1:0x7f935195fa40], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 2
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.086+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1548976295:86288][1:0x7f935195fa40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.141+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.233+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.306+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongo_1    | 2019-01-31T23:11:35.316+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

EDIT 2 :
It seems that there is an [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/190#issuecomment-331694698) with mongodb, windows and macOS (because they use NTFS).
For now I added:

```
volume:
  mongodata:
```

between networks and services in docker-compose.yml and it works

Comment: Can you please run `docker-compose logs mongo` and paste the result here?

Comment: - Why do you have custom network declaration?

- Why do you expose ports on the mongo service?

- How does your local folder ./data/db look like?

- Why do you want to persist data in local folder and not named docker volume?

Comment: @michalhosna, To explain you totally the situation, I have a school project where I need to create a Mean app, this app need to be launch with a docker-compose which build an express container and an angular container from 2 dockerfile and a mongodb container from the official image. In this project, we need to use a network for the communication between the containers and also we need to persist the mongodb database on the host machine.